# Show all Line Chart Labels Matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have dataset

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJyav.png)

| Period | Demand | Forecast | Error |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1401.0 | 338.0 | 1063.0 |
| 1 | 1840.0 | 345.0 | 1495.0 |
| 2 | 1242.0 | 341.0 | 901.0 |
| 3 | 1321.0 | 1500.0 | -179.0 |
| 4 | 711.0 | 1500.0 | -789.0 |

I already create plot using code

```
df[['Demand','Forecast']].plot(figsize=(8,3),title='Profil 2022',style=['-','--'])
plt.tight_layout()
```

this create plot like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVr0f.png)

but I need to show the data label of the line and I tried plot like this

```
plt.plot(df[['Demand','Forecast']])

for a in zip(df[['Demand','Forecast']]):
    label = df.index
    plt.annotate(label, (df[['Demand','Forecast']]),
                 xycoords="data",
                 textcoords="offset points",
                 xytext=(0, 10), ha="center")

plt.show()
```

The error is: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Honestly, I have no clue to show the data label of line chart, I tried googling and find the plt.annotate but still to hard for me.

Thanks

Comment: What's data label of the line?

Comment: @Ynjxsjmh the data itself, I want to show data label 1401 in line Demand and period 0, data label 338 in line Forecast and period 0